# How can I count the number of element comparisons in the Quicksort algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, quicksort

When given an array of elements, how can I count the amount of element comparisons the algorithm performs?

It's not as easy as just adding a counter to the partition method.

```
private void partition(int low, int high) {
    int i = low, j = high;
    // Get the pivot element from the middle of the list
    int pivot = numbers[low + (high-low)/2];

    // Divide into two lists
    while (i <= j) {

        if (array[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
            compareCount++; //it's not as easy as just adding this here
        }
        else if (numbers[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
            compareCount++;
        }

        else (i <= j) {
            exchange(i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
```

You can't do this because it counts the comparison just made, and not any of the comparisons made when it evaluates to false.

I've tried changing the `if (array[i] < pivot)` to `while (array[i] < pivot)` (for j, too), but I feel like I'm still missing out on something if I do it that way.

Comment: instead you must count the no of swaps.I think i am not able to interpret what you actually want,could please clarify a bit more.Also in else if portion why are you doing ++comparecounter?

Comment: I left it in there originally because when sorting an array of all equal elements, that's the only way I could tell when the elements are being sorted.

Comment: you were on the right path when you were doing while(array[i]<pivot).A little modification in the partition would solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should be able to do it by analyzing the logic. But if you want to have the program do it for you during its run-time then,  easy way to do this is to have a function for performing comparison operation. Let the function increment a global/static variable everytime it is called and then do the comparison. At the end of all your logic just print this global/Static variable.

```
    public class Myclass{

    public static int compareCount = 0;

    }

    /*
    * PASS parameter comparisonMethod as following
    * 0 for ==, 1 for >, 2 for >=, 3 for < and 4 for <==
    *  Method returns true or false by doing appropriate comparison based on comparisonMethod 
    */

    public bool compare(int i, int j, int comparisonMethod)
    {
      Myclass.compareCount++;
      if(comparisionMethod ==0) return i==j?true:false;
      if(comparisionMethod ==1) return i>j?true:false;
      if(comparisionMethod ==2) return i>=j?true:false;
      if(comparisionMethod ==3) return i<j?true:false;
      if(comparisionMethod ==4) return i<=j?true:false;   
    }


    private void partition(int low, int high) {
        int i = low, j = high;
        // Get the pivot element from the middle of the list
        int pivot = numbers[low + (high-low)/2];

        // Divide into two lists
        while (compare(i, j, 4)) {

            if (compare(array[i], pivot, 3)) {
                i++;
            }
            else if (compare(numbers[j], pivot, 2)) {
                j--;
            }

            else (compare(i, j, 4)) {
                exchange(i, j);
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
// At the end of the logic, Myclass.compareCount wil give number of comparisons made.
```

Comment: I don't think you need the first or last comparisons, since those are only elements *position* variables instead of the actual elements they're comparing. In that case, if you remove those two, is it still catching every single element comparison?

Comment: don't you think you have domplex the things a bit.I think a simple modification in the Partition program would do the trick.Please check my algorithm

Comment: @David Since the function compare is called for every comparison you do, it should catch everything.
@Algorithmist i actually wanted to simplify the problem by separating the logic for counting comparisons out of partition method. I felt it is easier to approach this instead of tying up everything in one place. Having said that, it is just one way of doing it.  There are other ways like the one you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The parition method of quick sort would be called till the size of array is not 1 in which case our array would be sorted.In your code when you have founf the position at which pivot would be swapped (in your else if portion)you are not supposed to incrment the comparecounter.

You can use this modified partition method

```
partition(A,p,r)
{

    pivot=A[r]; // Taking last element as pivot
    i=p;
    j=r;

    while (true)
    {

        while(A[i] < pivot && i <= r )
        {

            ++comparecounter;
            ++i;

        }

        while(A[j] >= pivot && j >= 0)
        {

            --j;
            ++comparecount;

        }

        if(i < j)
        {

            Exchange A[i] and A[j]

        }
        else
        {
            return j;
        }
```

In above algorithm you could make countcompare as global which would would incrment fro each call to partition.This would would count the no of comparisions made.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the compare count increment inside each if statement...

```
    if ((compareCount++ != -1) && (array[i] < pivot))
    ...
    else if ((compareCount++ != -1) && (numbers[j] > pivot))
    ...
    else if ((compareCount++ != -1) &&  (i <= j))
```

It'll always evaluate the first clause of the if, always return true, and always then execute the second.